# Doubly Circular Link List Implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

This are my classes for the nodes and linked list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>  

using namespace std;
//template <class Object>


//template <class Object>
class Node
{   
    //friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Node&c);
public:
    Node( int d=0);
    void print(){
        cout<<this->data<<endl;
    }
//private:
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    int data;

    friend class LinkList;
};
Node::Node(int d):data(d)
{

}

//template <class Object>
class LinkList
{
public:
    //LinkList();
    LinkList():head(NULL),tail(NULL),current(NULL){}
    int base;
    //LinkList(const LinkList & rhs, const LinkList & lhs);
    ~LinkList(){delete head,tail,current;}

    const Node& front() const;//element at current
    const Node& back() const;//element following current 
    void move();
    void insert (const Node & a);//add after current
    void remove (const Node &a);
    void create();
    void print();
private:
    Node* current;//current
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;


};

void LinkList::print()
{
    Node *nodePt =head;
    while(nodePt)
    {
        cout<<"print function"<<endl;
        cout<<nodePt->data<<endl;
        nodePt=nodePt->next;
    }
}
//element at current

void LinkList::create()
{
    Node start(0);

}

const Node& LinkList::back()const
{
    return *current;
}
//element after current
const Node& LinkList::front() const
{
    return *current ->next;
}

void LinkList::move()
{
    current = current ->next;
}
//insert after current 
void LinkList :: insert(const Node& a)
{
    Node* newNode= new Node();
    newNode->prev=current;
    newNode->next=current->next;
    newNode->prev->next=newNode;
    newNode->next->prev=newNode;
    current=newNode;

}
void LinkList::remove(const Node& a)
{
    Node* oldNode;
    oldNode=current;
    oldNode->prev->next=oldNode->next;
    oldNode->next->prev=oldNode->prev;
    delete oldNode;

}


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"How many Nodes would you like to create"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    Node a(n);
    Node b(n+1);
    a.print();
    a.next=&b;


    LinkList list1 ;
    list1.create();

    list1.print();
    list1.insert(0);
    list1.print();

    //for(int i=0 ;i<n;i++)
    //{
        //list1.insert(i);
    //}
```

I am suppose to be creating a doubly circular linked list, but i am now have problems created the actual linked list. Is the a problem with the classes. Also for the assignment the list is suppose to be a template class, but now i just want to get the code to work. Im not sure how to create the linked list properly.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: There is no description of the problem, other than needing somebody to complete a homework assignment. Some of your methods don't even make sense, did you just copy it from some other place? I don't think we can really be helpful in any way other than saying "open up your text book on data structures and/or C++".

Answer (score 1):

1 - You have to indent your code, make it clean before posting !!

2 - be specific in your question, i didn't get your problems

anyway, i saw code at all and i have noticed many things, may be they aren't all of your problems

1 - what does create function do ? i see that it do nothing, according to your logic - as i guessed - you should initialize your head, tail and current in this function by using parameters for example or ignore this function at all if it do nothing and then handle the case of inserting at the beginning in your insert function, and here is your second problem

2 - your insert function should take care of some conditions, insert at the beginning and at the end of the list

for example if insert at the end, this statement "newNode->next->prev" wouldn't be valid cause your next now is null

Don't forget to keep your head and tail updated after handling these conditions

Also why do you update current in the end of the insert function ? despite you can avoid its problems, i don't think it is logically accepted, it is better to make the role of "insert" to just insert, specially when you have a move function

3 - in remove function you should handle same conditions of remove function i mentioned above

4 - in main function :
What are those lines for?!!!

```
Node a(n);
Node b(n+1);
a.print();
a.next=&b;
```

i don't know if they were just testing lines for the node class,if not you should notice that it isn't LOGICAL AT ALL to create a node by the size of the linked list, i really don't know the reason for doing this !!

Take care if you have any confliction between node and linked list !

Revise all of your code again and take care of conditions you may face.

Hope i helped